# Split the given array into K sub-arrays such that maximum sum of all sub arrays is minimum

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, dynamic-programming

For a given array I am trying to calculate the Min-Max subarrays. Here is my code for calculating. I have derived the subproblem and tried to do it using dynamic programming (Using only recursion, not memoization or tabulation). Please let me know what is wrong because it is showing list cannot be iterpreted as an integer.

Update: I have updated the code. Please check and let me know what is wrong. Because it is saying that the min() arg is an empty sequence.

```
def Opt(i,j,S):
    if (j==1):
        return sum(S[:i])
    else:
        val = [max(Opt(l,j-1,S), sum(S[l:j])) for l in range(1,i,1)]
        return min(val)


# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    S = [5, 7, 4, 2, 1, 6]
    k = 3
    n = len(S)
    ans = Opt(n,k,S)
    print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

`range(1,i,1)` and `sum(i[l:j]))` are the problem. Your code is treating the first parameter of `Opt()` as both a list and an integer, producing a TypeError during your recursive `Opt()` call

Comment: len(i) also is not working.

Comment: What is the issue or new error?

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: Ok I see the problem a bit clearer. I think the issue is that the first argument for Opt() is   written both as list and an integer at different times (on entry, the code thinks of `i` as a list & for `sum(i[l:j]))`; on recursion, it uses `i` as an int for `range()`). It can't be both.

Comment: but I have edited it to len(i) for the 2nd case. It still is not working. i is a list not an integer so len(i) should return an integer. But still it is showing type error.

Comment: Except for during the recursion, when `Opt(l,j-1)` is called, and `l` is an integer made from range(). In that case, `i` becomes an int. Then, `sum(i[l:j])` expects a list and finds an integer

Comment: yes I found it thanks. Lets see if I can fix it.

Comment: Ok so I have fixed the code like this. Can you tell me what else needs to be fixed? Because it is saying min value is empty.
'''
def Opt(i,j,S):
    if (j==1):
        return sum(S[:i])
    else:
        val = [max(Opt(l,j-1,S), sum(S[l:j])) for l in range(1,i,1)]
        return min(val)



# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    S = [5, 7, 4, 2, 1, 6]
    k = 3
    n = len(S)
    ans = Opt(n,k,S)
    print(ans)
'''

Comment: You should edit your original post with that new piece of code and see if anyone can help out.

Comment: Done. Please check now.